# analyse time series at a specific frequency

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have a long data set of water temperature:

```
t = 1/24:1/24:365;
y = 1 + (30-1).*rand(1,length(t));
plot(t,y)
```

The series extends for one year and the number of measurements per day is 24 (i.e. hourly). I expect the water temperature to follow a diurnal pattern (i.e. have a period of 24 hours), therefore I would like to evaluate how the 24 hour cycle varies throughout the year. Is there a method for only looking at specific frequencies when analyzing a signal? If so, I would like to draw a plot showing how the 24 hour periodicity in the data varies through the year (showing for example if it is greater in the summer and less in the winter). How could I do this?

Comment: shouldn't you look at the mean in a given period, instead of looking at one single point in time? Averaging reduces the amount of noise, so you'll get a smoother overall plot imo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `reshape` to transform your data to a `24x365` matrix. In the new matrix every column is a day and every row a time of day.

```
temperature=reshape(y,24,365);
time=(1:size(temperature,1))-1;
day=(1:size(temperature,2))-1;
[day,time]=meshgrid(day,time);

surf(time,day,temperature)
```

Comment: This is a very good answer. I would also recommend doing that.

Answer (score 0):

- My first thought would be fourier transformation. This will give you a frequency spectrum.
  At *high* frequencies (> 1/d) you would have the pattern for a day, at low frequencies the patter over longer times. (see lowpass and highpass filter)
- Also you could go for a frequency/time visualization that will show how the frequencies change over a year.
- A bit more work - but you could write a simple model and create a Kalman filter for it.

Comment: I have plotted the data in a time-frequency domain (wavelets) but I do not require all of the a periodicities in the data, I only one those with a period of 1/24, the wavelet shows all of the periods that make up the data.

Comment: I think wavelets are no good for you as they always have frequencies which are a power of two. But you could do the same manually by doing fourier transforms on 24 hour sections.

Comment: Fourier transform is overdoing it -- a simple bandpass filter is sufficient. Wavelets in general are not just power of two, just the discrete wavelet transform on the dyadic grid is. Kalman-filtering is just completely wrong for that kind of task, since it is not an analysis-tool! Kalman-filter are used for prediction.

Comment: oh - didn't know that about wavelets. But I disagree about Kalman filter. I almost exclusively use them to estimate state space parameter.